# I have integrated a bash command into my Python code - how can I get this command to take an input from the shell?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have added a bash command to my Python script - this bash command is used to linearise an input file (i.e. take a file with many lines, and merge it into one line). It works when I manually write the name of the file for the command (in this example, the input file is called input.txt):

```
import subprocess

holder = subprocess.Popen('perl -ne "chomp;print;" input.txt', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print(holder)
```

However, I would like this bash command to take the name of the file specified by the user in the command line, and linearise it.

I have already tried to achieve this using `%s`:

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

path = sys.argv[1]
file = open(path, 'r')
inp = file.read()

holder = subprocess.Popen('perl -ne "chomp;print;" %s' % inp, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print(holder)
```

However, when I try this, the shell freezes and shows no output, and the bash `$` prompt does not show, there is no error message.

I would like to know if there is a valid way to add a user input in this case and would appreciate any help.

EDIT: just to clarify, here is what I type into my shell to run the program with the second example:

`$ python3 program.py input.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just directly feed the input path to your subprocess, like this? I'm slightly confused as to why you would like to use perl within python do this however..

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

path = sys.argv[1]

holder = subprocess.Popen('perl -ne "chomp;print;" %s' % path, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print(holder)
```

with this example input:

```
test.txt
i
i
i
i
i
```

the program will output:

```
python linearize.py test.txt
b'iiiii'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I realise that it's not good practice, but in this case I am pressed for time - as a beginner in Python it was taking me too long to work out how to linearise the type of file I'm inputting using Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os

holder = subprocess.Popen('perl -ne "chomp;print;" {}'.format(sys.argv[1]), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()

print(holder)
```

But why ? Why calling a perl script using python ? Python has all the tools you need to do the same using native, debuggable and crossplatform code on one process. It does not make sense and it is a bad practice.

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as input_file:
    holder = ''.join(input_file.read().splitlines())

print(holder)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I realise that it's not good practice, but in this case I am pressed for time - as a beginner in Python it was taking me too long to work out how to linearise the type of file I'm inputting using Python.

Comment: Btw, searching "remove carriage return + python" on SO gives you hundreds of solutions.

Comment: I have since realised that the perl script is not good for my purpose, as I am working with FASTA files and need to maintain separation of sequences. Your Python code works perfectly for what I described in this question though. However, I have posted a new question with a different command now.